# Is it possible to return back a parameter using model through POST method in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Suppose we have the below code in our spring mvc Controller method :

```
boolean jobKilled = true;
model.addAttribute("jobKilled", jobKilled);
return "redirect:/{username}/jobs";
```

now,after redirect the user url form this way:

```
localhost:8080/Project/{username}/jobs?jobKilled=true
```

what if I dont want the parameter part (?jobKilled=true) get shown after redirection & I be able to fetch the model inside my jsp?

is it possible that I send back the model to the view using post & fetch that inside my jsp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [flash attributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes) in spring-mvc. I think it was designed for your very use-case.